# Simplify expression $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{15}(\frac{1}{3})^{n - 2}$

Tags: calculus

How can I simplify the above expression? I try to use sum of geometric series but it does not work. Any hints?

Comment: It's not a geometric series, but note that $\dfrac 1 {(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this sum, we'll need the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=m}^M x^n = x^m\sum_{k=0}^{M-m} x^k = x^m \frac{x^{M+1-m}-1}{x-1} = \frac{x^{M+1}-x^m}{x-1}$$

for $m<M$. Now notice that

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n}{15} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-2} = \frac{2}{15} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n = \frac{2}{15} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n + \frac{4}{15} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$$

The sum on the right is

$$\frac{4}{15} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{2}{5}$$

In order to do the sum on the left without calculus, recognize that

$$\frac{2}{15} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n = \frac{2}{15} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$$

then swap the order of the summation:

$$\frac{2}{15} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n = \frac{2}{15} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{2}{15}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2} = \frac{1}{10}$$

Thus the final sum is $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

I would start by noticing that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{15}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-2} =
\frac{2}{5}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}
\end{align*}
which is the derivative of the geometric series applied to $x = 1/3$. To be precise, one has

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-x}\,\,(\text{for}\,\,|x| < 1)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?